# Unsmooth keyframe animation using CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a keyframe animation within my site; it is extremely basic but it seems to be running a little 'glitchy'.

I appreciate that this could be due to many factors but as I do not have extensive experience with CSS Keyframes, I was hoping someone would be willing to look at my code and ascertain whether I am doing it correctly?

Here is my code:

```css
div {display:block;position:absolute;left:0;bottom:20px;right:0;text-align:center;z-index:2;}
a {display:inline-block;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:600;letter-spacing:2px;color:#000;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;}
a:after {content:'\f107';display:block;font-family:FontAwesome;font-size:30px;margin:5px auto 0;animation:bounce 2s infinite;}

/* Scroll down bounce */
@keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
 50% {transform: translateY(-10px);}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a>Scroll Down</a>
</div>
```

### Bonus

Ideally I would actually like the animation to bounce in order to stand out more but I failed to get this to to work. If anyone can see a way to amend this to apply a more 'bounce' effect I would very much appreciate it...

Comment: its just because the animation-duration is too high `2s` and the transform distance is low, either lower the duration or increase the `transformY` http://jsfiddle.net/1jbwmerq/

Comment: @RohitKumar That's a very good point, thank you

Comment: posted that as an answer so that future readers find it helpful, it answered only half part so I updated the bounce animation also to feel like bouncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by ***bounce***. You could add a couple more keyframe animations to make it seem like its bouncing a little when it hits the bottom:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jbwmerq/2/)

```
 @keyframes bounce {
    0%, 70%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    50%, 85% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that I have seen the bounce effect, I think I will keep it as it is as it doesn't look quite as good as I had hoped... But as you answered the question I will accept. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Its just because the `animation-duration` is too high `2s` and the transform distance is low, either lower the `duration` or increase the `transformY` - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1jbwmerq/)

Also you can make the animation feel like bouncing by adjusting the `transform` values at different `keyframes`, just for example -

```
@keyframes bounce {
    50% {transform: translateY(0);}
    0%, 25%, 75%, 100% {transform: translateY(-10px);}
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1jbwmerq/3/)